# Elasticsearch search explain query with fieldNorm

Tags: search, elasticsearch, full-text-search, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-5

```
{ "query": { "match" : { "name": "abcd" } } }

    Hits: {
        "index" : "indexuniq_v5",
        "_type" : "Playlist",
        "_id" : "49680",
        "_score" : 0.5945348,
        "_source" : {
        "name" : "abcd",
        "ratin" : 4
    }
    }, {
        "index" : "indexuniq_v5",
        "_type" : "Playlist",
        "_id" : "49682",
        "_score" : 0.5945348,
        "_source" : {
        "name" : "abcdeert",
        "ratin" : 4
    }
}
```

If see _explain, all details score have equal value. And fieldNorm too :confused:

Why scores are equal?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html